# Dynamic Row Shading with Conditional Formatting Formulas - EXCEL

Tags: vba, excel

I have a document with functionality via data validation selection. Each selection triggers a macro to hide certain rows. I have the following conditional formatting formula =MOD(ROW(),2)=1 and it works great when all rows are unhidden, however I'm looking for a more dynamic formula that can change when the rows are automatically hidden. I'm open to using VBA in lieu of conditional formatting.

Comment: Why not use a table, The table will always show shading every other row regardless of filtering.

Comment: This particular document is not formatted for a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUBTOTAL` to count non-hidden rows.  This relies on a column being filled (ie no blanks).  I've used column A, use a different one if you need to.

Conditional Format formula

```
=MOD(SUBTOTAL(103,A1:$A$1),2)=1
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you!