# alternate cell shading on each group in col2

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to "walk" through a Excel column and if the the preceding or following cell has the same value or single, mark it with a color.
For example:

[image: example pic]

i have get this by  creating an auxiliary column.Can anyone goal this without VBA nor an auxiliary column.
[my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYYX9.png)

Comment: What do you mean "or single"?  Is your goal to alternate cell shading on each group in `col2`?

Comment: single --> like row 6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternating coloring groups of rows in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27020/alternating-coloring-groups-of-rows-in-excel)  There are various other examples of hoe to do this as well, such as **[this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+alternate+shading+group).**

Comment: yes,i want to alternate cell shading on each group in col2.

Comment: thx ,but i want to konw if anyone can goal this without using VBA nor an auxiliary column

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492425/excel-conditional-formatting-for-clusters-of-values/16493622#16493622

Comment: Alright, that's also possible with the help of conditional formatting. See the link from @teylyn or also this one: ["Dynamic Row Shading with Conditional Formatting Formulas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39733229/dynamic-row-shading-with-conditional-formatting-formulas-excel) and others.

Comment: thx all.This is confirmed that can't alternate cell shading on each group in col2 without VBA nor an auxiliary column

Answer (score 0):

Select ColumnsA:B, clear any CF from it and then HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=ISODD(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($B1:$B$9,$B1:$B$9)))
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select blue Fill, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.